# Specify variable in array - PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I don't know if it's because i've been staring at the screen for too long or what, but I cannot seem to get this right.

This works (token hardcoded):

```
$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key = xxxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);
```

What I want to do is specify the token as a variable, held in `$notification_id`

I have tried all kinds of things like:

```
$headers = array
(
    "Authorization: key = " => "$notification_id",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$headers = array
(
    "Authorization: key = " . $notification_id,
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);

$headers = array
(
    "Authorization: key = $notification_id",
    "Content-Type: application/json"
);
```

But get an authentication error every time.

Ultimately this is being used here :

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
?>
```

I imagine this is something stupid, but I've been sat here for too long staring at the screen and am clearly missing something obvious! Thanks.

Comment: Second $headers has an extra double quote, but that might just be a typo in the post.

Comment: @CMiller yes, typo, apologies. Will correct

Comment: Could you maybe for testing purposes to a print_r of the one that works, and a print_r of the second or third option and see if you see any differences and just to confirm the variable is correct?

Comment: I'm echoing out the variable on send (not shown in code) to make double sure it's there, but I'll try that, thanks.

Comment: So I just added the print_r($headers) and it showed the variable and it worked, took out the print_v line and now it works just fine... Arghhh! THanks @CMiller

Comment: Solar flare probable...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea why this has started working, but this is what I have used, I'm SURE i used it before and it didn't work...

```
$headers = array
    (
        "Authorization: key = " . $notification_id,
        "Content-Type: application/json"
    );
```